# gradle multiple repositories doesn't work

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-dokka

```
repositories {
  maven {
    url "https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/gradle-plugin"
  }
  gradlePluginPortal()
}
```

error:

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':buildSrc:compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find dokka-gradle-plugin-1.5.0.jar (org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-gradle-plugin:1.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/gradle-plugin/org/jetbrains/dokka/dokka-gradle-plugin/1.5.0/dokka-gradle-plugin-1.5.0.jar
   > Could not find dokka-core-1.5.0.jar (org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-core:1.5.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/gradle-plugin/org/jetbrains/dokka/dokka-core/1.5.0/dokka-core-1.5.0.jar
```

If I use `gradlePluginPortal()` only:

```
repositories {
  //maven {
  //  url "https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/gradle-plugin"
  //}
  gradlePluginPortal()
}
```

All OK.

I know that is because `maven` repo has no `dokka-core-1.5.0.jar`, but why not download from `gradlePluginPortal`?

Comment: What happens if you swap the order of the repositories?

Comment: @dan1st It works if swap. But I want to know why gradle doesn't try next repo if prev download failed.

Comment: I have a same issue with my project, have you find any solution or explanation of that behaviour?

Comment: @NikitaChegodaev saddly no